# Cat one file onto same named file in another directory

Tags: bash, unix, find, cat

I am trying to cat the contents of *.txt onto another file with the same name in another directory. E.g.  `../../*.txt`

I have tried:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec cat {} \; >> ../../*.txt
```

And some variations on it but end up with an ambiguous redirect error or nothing at all.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` does not do a one-to-one mapping. It will be expanded by bash to represent all the txt files in the `../../` directory. This is causing the error since now you are trying to redirect to multiple files.

It might be easier to do this using a for loop rather than find since you need to refer to the filename twice.

```
for file in *.txt
do
    if [ -f ./$file ] ; then 
        cat ./$file >> ../../$file
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

For 1 file:

```
cat ./file1.txt >> ../../file1.txt
```

Your question suggests 1 file but your `find` command suggests many files of the type `*.txt`

To do multiple files of the type `*.txt` and based on your `find` command try:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' filename
do
  cat ./$filename >> ../../$filename
done
```

Answer (score 0):

> cat the contents of *.txt onto another file with the same name

Essentially you're copying files here. Aint you?

So below stuff should work for you.

```
find . -type f -iname "*.txt" -exec cp bash -c 'cp "$1" ../../"$1"' _ {} \;
```